# How to create jar file in intellij

Tags: java

I am using intellij community version . I am creating a jar file via build artifact but I am getting file size 67357KB . Which is very big .How to create proper jar file .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A "proper" JAR file can be very big.  So you are probably creating it the right way.

So what you really need to do is to examine the JAR file to see what the build has put into it.  If there is stuff in the JAR that shouldn't be there, you then need to look at what your Maven POM file, Gradle file, or whatever to figure out why the build puts the unwanted stuff in there.

If you are not using Maven, Gradle or some other build system, check the [artifact configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiling-applications.html#package_into_jar) that you have created to specify what goes in the JAR, and what is in the directories you have told it to include.